# VGA touch monitor adjustment

Tags: multi-monitor, resolution

Playing with a 7" Lilliput wide screen VGA TFT touch monitor. *(From a Shuttle X SN45G.)*

Issue I have is that the 7", running 1024x768, display only show (about) two thirds of the screen. Dat is:

My main (HDMI) monitor is 1920x1080 and the 7" show 1024x768 of this:

[image: Main monitor vs lilliput]

Question is if I can display the actual screen on the Lilliput without lowering the resolution on my main screen from 1920x1080 to 10024x768 … as in having two resolutions, if you get what I mean?

(I have second issue with pointer position, but I thought of might asking that in a different question if this Q is answered positively.)

Have played around with `xrandr`, but mostly made a mess ...